# New passport with new last name, H-1B stamp in old passport

Tags: visa, h1-visa, passport

I have a somewhat entangled situation. I’m in the US under H-1B. I am traveling to Germany (my home country) over the holidays. My passport expires in February so I can’t re-enter with that passport.

However the time I am in Germany is not enough to get a new passport and a new visa stamp. On top of that, my last name changed due to marriage (in the form of -, so my old name is still somewhat there).

Now here’s the question: can I travel to Germany, get a passport with my new name, and then enter the US with that new passport, showing them the visa stamp in my old passport?

Comment: Take the marriage certificate with you, should be fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A different name on Green Card and foreign passport - is this a problem during exit or re-entry while living in USA?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/a-different-name-on-green-card-and-foreign-passport-is-this-a-problem-during-e)

Comment: I think the green card question is a bit different as I will also have two different passports with different names. Also, the marriage certificate and name change certificate are in German, so I wonder if they would even consider looking at that?